# Does SqlRowSet not recognize column name aliases?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I just switched over from using plain old connections to JdbcTemplate, and when I ran my application I received this:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: Invalid column name; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

I found that SqlRowSet does not recognize column name aliases when you use its getXXX methods. Is there a way around this using SqlRowSet? Or do I just have to use the full column names or indices for these columns instead?

Thanks in advance,

ktm

Comment: What database are you using? Maybe a casing issue? Show more of the code both old and new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about SqlRowSet, but if you don't **need** a disconnected ResultSet (SqlRowSet), another option is to use one of the query methods that takes a RowMapper as a parameter. The RowMapper will get passed a ResultSet, which should support the alias.

Answer (score 0):

In the class ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet source,

```
public class ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet implements SqlRowSet
```

the wrapped method like getXXX use the field 'label' not the field name.

```
public int getInt(String columnLabel) throws InvalidResultSetAccessException {
    return getInt(findColumn(columnLabel));
}


public int findColumn(String columnLabel) throws InvalidResultSetAccessException {
    Integer columnIndex = this.columnLabelMap.get(columnLabel);
    if (columnIndex != null) {
        return columnIndex;
    }
    else {
        try {
            return this.resultSet.findColumn(columnLabel);
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            throw new InvalidResultSetAccessException(se);
        }
    }
}
```

[ResultSetMetaData#getColumnLabel(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel%28int%29) doc link.

```
public ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws InvalidResultSetAccessException {
    this.resultSet = resultSet;
    try {
        this.rowSetMetaData = new ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSetMetaData(resultSet.getMetaData());
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
        throw new InvalidResultSetAccessException(se);
    }
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
        if (rsmd != null) {
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            this.columnLabelMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(columnCount);
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                this.columnLabelMap.put(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i), i);
            }
        }
        else {
            this.columnLabelMap = Collections.emptyMap();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
        throw new InvalidResultSetAccessException(se);
    }

}
```

So you need check your sql and the database configuration(supporting database metadata fetching from sql).

Comment: ResultSet has no problem recognizing the column aliases, so it shouldn't be a problem with the SQL or the database configuration.